# How to redirect to a Page or a path in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

So, I have this application that looks like this:

```
Pages
 ├─Restricted
 │  ├─Index
 │  └─SecretPage
 ├─Index
 └─UserPage
```

`Index` page allows anonymous access and has the login form, `UserPage` page can be accessed by any Authenticated user, and pages in `Restricted` folder can be accessed by only authorized users.

An unauthenticated user might try to access `UserPage` page or the pages in `Restricted` folder, but then they'll be redirected to `Index` pages (in the root) to log in. In this case, the URL will be something like `https://example.com/?returnUrl=UserPage` or `https://example.com/?returnUrl=Restricted`.

To redirect the user after the login to where they wanted to go, I had the following code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectTarget = string.Empty;

    // try to authenticate the user

    if (/* the log in attempt is successful */)
    {
        // do the log in stuff; i.e., Claims and SignInAsync

        redirectTarget = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) ? "UserPage" : returnUrl;
    }

    return RedirectToPage(redirectTarget);
}
```

This works fine as long as `returnUrl` is a page; However, when `returnUrl` is a folder; e.g., `Restricted`, it throws "InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Restricted' matches the supplied values."

So, I switched to `Redirect(redirectTarget)`, but this one incorrectly redirects the user to `Index/UserPage` instead of `UserPage`, in case `returnUrl` was `null` or empty. Also, it means that I need to hardcode the login/current page URL; i.e., `/`, instead of depending to the redirect method to redirect the user to the same page in case of unsuccessful login attempt, like what `RedirectToPage` does.

I can solve the redirect to `UserPage` issue by using `/UserPage` instead of `UserPage`; i.e., prefix it with a `/`. However, this means that the web site cannot be hosted in a virtual directory, because `UserPage` won't be in the root of the website.

Any clean way to do this kind of redirect?

P.S. the application is using ASP.NET Core 2.2 running on .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: What version of dotnet core are you using?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck, .NET Core 2.2. Updated the question to say that as well.